# Non abelian group of order 1575

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

Construct a non abelian group of order $1575$.

I am sure I am to use semi direct product.Give me some idea/hint to start.

Comment: Start by listing possible alternatives for Sylow $p$-subgroups. To get a non-trivial semi direct product you need one of them to have a group of automorphisms that can appear as homomorphic images of the others. What  do you know about the automorphism groups of the listed alternatives?

Comment: Can you construct a  non-abelian group G of order 21?.  If so, then form the direct product of G with any (say abelian) group of order 75.  The result is non-abelian of order 21*75=1575.

Comment: @johng done! thank you